# Finding index of the parent node

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I put breakpoint on line 76 as you can see. Then I went to console, typed the below commands.

I'm unable to get the index or row value of the clicked element. What am I missing?

[image]

Code snippet:

```
<td>
   <a href="doc4.html" name="doc4" target="_blank">doc4</a>
   <span class="arrow"></span>
   <div class="toggle" style="display: none;">
      <div><a href="image_3.1.jpg" name="image" target="_blank">image</a></div>
      <div><a href="testingwrongtype_2.2.gif" name="testingwrongtype" target="_blank">testingwrongtype</a></div>
      <div><a href="vsd_2_1.2.png" name="vsd_2" target="_blank">vsd_2</a></div>
      <div><a href="BMP_1.3.bmp" name="BMP" target="_blank">BMP</a></div>
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: you have to say `this.parentNode.parentNode` - there is no property called `parent`, it is `parentNode`

Comment: @ArunPJohny parent() is valid method. No issue

Comment: `this` is DOM element, not jQuery object.

Comment: @EOF that is if jQuery is used... in this case OP is accessing the properties from a dom element reference not from a jQuery object

Comment: @ArunPJohny: That gives me the current `<tr>`, how can I get the row number now? I tried `this.parentNode.parentNode.index();` That didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried: `$(this).closest('tr').index()` ???

Comment: you need to say `this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex`

Comment: @ChankeyPathak there is no method called index for the tr element reference, you have a property called rowIndex for the [tr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex)

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Thanks. Add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your console, `this` refers to the dom element not a jQuery object so it does not have a property called `parent` instead it has `parentNode`. Also the `tr` element does not have a method called `index` it has a property `rowIndex`. So

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex
```

or if you want to use jQuery then

```
$(this).closest('tr').index()
```

Comment: It works fine in console. When I added this in my app as `$(".arrow").click(function () {                
     alert( this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex() );` it shows error `number is not a function`.

Comment: again rowIndex is not a function so `alert(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);` or use the jQuery equivalent `alert($(this).closest('tr').index())`